# Merging two oracle database instances in one instance

Tags: database, oracle, merge

I have an environment where data from different versions of the same application (which runs on top of an Oracle database) need to be merged into a single database instance. From a database point of view, each version runs on top of a single schema and in addition to the standard objects (tables, procedures, sequences, constraints, etc), each version has a set of user definied tables that also needs to be present on the new instance.

Considering the implications of this type of merge (PK/FK collisions between standard tables, sequence/index rebuilding, etc.), what would be the best merge strategy for this case?

Comment: What is the purpose of the merged database? Reporting only? You may wish to consider building a data warehouse (which allows for this by adding an additional surrogate key)

Comment: Mainly for reducing maintenance and licensing costs and for reporting purposes. Also, the different versions of the application were representations of different customer's facilities, that now will be done in only one single facility.

Comment: The important question is: will there still be an application writing data into it? Do you have to preserve the schema?

Comment: The application uses a single schema to make data available to users in all instances, so I'll need to preserve the schema to allow viewing of historical data in the new instance. Initially I planned to move all the data from the older applications into new schemas, but the data would be inaccessible through the UI.

Comment: So is that a constraint? Data in the new schema needs to be accessible from the application? That's what my last two questions have really been asking.

Comment: Yes, the data will ned to be acessible from the application.

Comment: This means that the scheme needs to be identical. The simplest solution I this case is to add a magic number to lol of the keys in one database source. But it’s far from perfect.